# Can I use a vintage derailleur adapter claw on a modern derailleur

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, derailleur-hanger

I am restomoding a vintage Hi-C branded Schwinn road bike. There is no derailleur hanger on the drop outs so I am in need of an adapter claw. Can I remove this claw from the old derailleur or is the spring inside riveted and not threaded? Thanks in advance[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

These traditional claw hangers can be purchased new for a few dollars from any good LBS.  No need to wreck your vintage derailleur.

Your second photo suggests it is pressed together, not threaded. I did exactly this with a cheap modern tourney derailleur, and the hole was too big to take the thread so it was trashed for no gain.

[image]
<sub>Example from https://www.rearmechhanger.com/product/rear-gear-mech-derailleur-hanger-cc103/#</sub>

Comment: Agreed, but I suspect that depending on what derailleur and gearing you're using, you may have trouble getting indexing to work correctly with this setup.

Comment: @AdamRice true there - I ended up tweaking mine by adding a subtle Z bend to get more low-gear range.  My main point was that the salvaged hanger might not work because the pin diameter may not leave enough metal for threads.

Comment: In my city we have a non profit that has bins on bins on bins of used bike parts. I stripped an axel mount derailleur with a threaded hanger. It’s exactly like a claw adapter.

Answer (score 7):

> Can I remove this claw from the old derailleur or is the spring inside
> riveted and not threaded?

The spring is not riveted. The pin holding the derailleur to the derailleur hanger is riveted (EDITED: "rivet" is the wrong word. Pressed in would be better) to the derailleur hanger and has a "C" clip on the derailleur side. It is not designed work with a threaded derailleur
[image]

If your new derailleur does not come with a derailleur hanger you will need to buy/find one that will work. A quick search on "derailleur hanger" will turn up many options.

Answer (score -4):

Depending on your access to bike shops or collectors, if your running the same gear cluster, staying stock is relatively inexpensive...matching the cage (that holds the 2 pully wheels) is your primary concern. The spring cylinder comes in many designs.

Going with an internal geared hub/wheel and a grip shift style shifter has countless benefits, 2sp, 3sp, 5sp, 7sp, for recreation is popular option.

Comment: Welcome to the site - this has no relevance to OP's question.  Could you [edit] it to reference the use of a vintage derailleur hanger on a more modern derailleur?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more focus](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider editing your answer to more directly answer the original question. An answer like this that veers into unrelated territory is likely to get additional down votes, be flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.